# passing query params into json object angular

Tags: angular

i use routerLink with queryparams, and it work if i do like this:

```
[routerLink]="['/user/bob']" [queryParams]="{debug: true}"
```

but im using a theme, and in it the routes of menu navigation is defined in a json object and i try do it, but the params is undefined. My code:

```
{
  label: 'Produto', icon: 'fa fa-fw fa-sitemap',
  items: [{label: 'Produto Agil', icon: 'fa fa-fw fa-columns', routerLink: ['/produtoagil']},
          {label: 'Grupo', icon: 'fa fa-fw fa-code', routerLink: ['/grupo']},
          {label: 'Marca', icon: 'fa fa-fw fa-table', routerLink: ['/entidadesimples'], queryparams: {entidade: 'marca'}},
          {label: 'Secao', icon: 'fa fa-fw fa-list-alt', routerLink: ['/entidadesimples'], queryparams: {entidade: 'secao'}},
          {label: 'Categoria', icon: 'fa fa-fw fa-square', routerLink: ['/entidadesimples'], queryparams: {entidade: 'categoria'}},
          {label: 'Subcategoria', icon: 'fa fa-fw fa-minus-square-o', routerLink: ['/entidadesimples'], queryparams:{entidade: 'subcategoria'}},
          {label: 'Unidade Produto', icon: 'fa fa-fw fa-circle-o-notch', routerLink: ['/entidadesimples'], queryparams: {entidade: 'unidadeproduto'}}
         ]
}
```

and in ts i do it to capture params:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params =>{
    this.entidade = params['entidade']
    })
}
```

Comment: which theme dod you use? Check its API for query params

Comment: prime ng, i dont find it in documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see there is `queryParams` at [`menuitem interface`](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/common/menuitem.ts#L9). and I see it is implemented in the [template](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/menu/menu.ts#L15). So, just try to use `queryParams` with camelcase and not `queryparams` (lowercase will not work) like:

```
...
{
  label: 'Marca', 
  icon: 'fa fa-fw fa-table', 
  routerLink: ['/entidadesimples'], 
  queryParams: {entidade: 'marca'}
}
...
```

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-snhflr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmenu.component.ts)

Comment: I created a stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-snhflr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmenu.component.ts), everything works as expected